# Why binary file works perfectly outside the container but does not work inside of it

Tags: docker, gitlab, binary

I made a binary file (go app) with name "simply-work", it works perfectly when I run it in terminal

```
./simply-work --something=smth-test
```

I decided to use it in docker container, so I created Dockerfile

```
FROM docker:latest
COPY /local /usr/bin
```

Then I builded it, run it and in docker container try to use ./simply-work but it responses

```
MZ����@���: not found
syntax error: unterminated quoted string
```

The same thing when I use my binary in gitlab-ci.yml
So what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you compiled the binary for the right operating system and architecture?  (I'd normally expect a Linux binary to start with something like `ELF`; the `MZ` looks like it might be a Windows binary.)  Consider using a multi-stage build to run the Go toolchain in a container.  You should rarely if ever need the `docker` image.

Comment: @DavidMaze thank u for your answer! yeah, I compiled it on Windows, my mistake. Bytheway I need docker image for next docker commands in gitlab-ci jobs

Comment: @DavidMaze, now I compiled it on linux and running it with ./simply-work command and it says "not found" (in gitlab ci) or "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" (on windows)